# MIPS Program to Acces element of array

Tags: assembly, mips

hope you're doing okay in these days.  I am trying to convert my C++ code to mips but im struggling on some points. First of all this is my C++ code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int matrix[2][5] = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10} };

int rowSize = 2;
int colSize = 5;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int main()
{
    while (i < rowSize) {

        if (j < colSize) {

            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
            j++;

        }
        else {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my MIPS code:

```
.data
    matrix: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        .word 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

    rowSize: .word 2
    colSize: .word 5
    .eqv dataSize 4

    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    space:   .asciiz " "
.text

    main:
        la $a0, matrix   #Loading from Random access to registers.
        lw $s0, rowSize
        lw $s1, colSize

        li $t0,0     # i= row index
        li $t1,0     # j= col index

        jal printMatrix



        li $v0,10
        syscall 


    printMatrix:

        bge $t0, $s0, exitLoop                          # If  i < rowSize is false, exit the loop
        bge $t1, $s1, else              # If i<rowSize is true and j < colSize is false, jump to else 

        mul $t2, $t0, $s0                #Following the function address = baseAddr + ( rowIndex * colSize + colIndex) * byteSize
        add $t2, $t2, $t1
        mul $t2, $t2, dataSize
        add $t2, $t2, $a0

        lw $t3, 0($t2)

        li $v0,1            # printing element inf Array[i][j] each loop
        move $a1,$t3
        syscall

        li $v0,4            # printing space after each element
        la $a2, space
        syscall

        addi $t1, $t1, 1

        j printMatrix

    else:
        li $t1,0              # j = 0
        addi $t0, $t0, 1              # i++;

        li $v0,4
        la $a2, newLine          #Printing new line after printing one row
        syscall
        j printMatrix

    exitLoop:
        li $v0,10
        syscall             #terminate the program
```

So by following tutorials and stackoverflow posts, i see people were able to see outputs correctly by using the same method as me ( in my case correct input is:

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10

But this is the input i get:

268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx268500992xxx

xxx's are originally squares in output, changed to xx cause stackoverflow didn't print squares :)

Number of elements printed is true, i suppose squares are newlines ( no idea why it shows like this), but i have no idea why it prints 268500992 over and over again. Any clues?

Thank you and i wish you healthy days :)

Comment: Squares are what you get for an unprintable character, like a control code or something.  MARS does handle newline ('\n' = 0xa = 10) correctly, I think, allowing programs to produce multiple lines of output.  Single-step your program and see if something is modifying the newline character in memory you're using.  Also, you can use the print-character system call so you can just `li $a0, '\n'` instead of passing a pointer to a single-character string.

Comment: Try moving `$t3`into `$a0` instead of `$a1` before the syscall.  Do you know what 268500992 is in hex?  It's 0x10010000.  Do you know what that is?  Its the address of `matrix`.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks for the response, i was aware of the output being addres of $a0 (original matrix). Still have no idea to solve it unfortunately. I wrote a program to sum values in matrixes diagonal and i end up correct output. But when i try to  print each value before adding it to sum, it gives me adress of matrix as output

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the response! I tried every single way and still it prints squares, nothing unusual in memory too, i think problem might be in my java version.

Comment: **Use the debugger** built-in to MARS to single-step through your code and look at the args to a system call that prints a square.  Don't just change the source and run the whole thing; that's the worst way to debug assembly.  It's like trying to build a robot while blindfolded, and is a waste of your time (and everyone else's).

Comment: The MARS print-integer system call takes a value, not an address, in $a0, so `lw` the value not `la` the address.  Or however you got an address into `$a0`, dereference it if it's the *right* address.

Comment: @ege.yildirim, I told you how to solve it.  Hint: it's the first thing I said.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you, when i moved `$t3` to `$a0` instead of `$a0`, it gave me error, then i changed my original matrixes register to `$a1` and did what you told me, its working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, generally we want to avoid using `$a0` and `$v0` for long-lived variables b/c syscalls will clobber those.